# Can't send http request to a website in the same server

Tags: nginx

I have a website that is run by nginx on my server, and it's working properly, but when I try to send a `curl` request to it inside the server, it gets timed out!

In other words, the following command works well everywhere:

`curl <my-site-url>`

But when I run it from inside the server, it doesn't work!
Does anybody have any idea about it?

Below is the nginx config:

```
server {

listen 80;

server_name <my-site-url>;
client_max_body_size 50M;
keepalive_timeout    69;
error_log /home/ssc/logs/ssc_nginx_error.log;
access_log /home/ssc/logs/ssc_nginx_access.log;

location / {
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://something;
}
```

Comment: you have no chance for help, without posting here network configuration, nginx configs, firewall setting and SELinux state

Comment: "it doesn't work" what does it mean? what are the symptoms?

Comment: @IgorCova it gets timed out!

Comment: Do you put `http://`after comand curl?

Comment: @IgorCova Yeah it's exactly the same command as the correct one (on my local machine)